# Backup multiple Exchange Accounts without direct access to exchange server

Tags: backup, exchange, outlook, batch-processing

For e-mail, we use Microsoft Exchange and it is hosted by 1and1.com.

We have about 30 Exchange accounts that I would like to backup to a PST file.  That is, for each account that we have (all 30), I would like to create a single PST file (1.pst thru 30.pst).

I do not have direct access to the Exchange server.  Basically, for each Exchange account, I can supply:

1. The IP address for the Exchange server or the URL to the OWA.
2. The Username
3. The Password

**Is there a tool out there that can do this for me?**

It seems that Microsoft's "Online Services Migration Tools" comes awfully close, but it appears that its geared to pull data out of any Exchange server and push it into Microsoft Online.  I don't believe it can be used to simply pull the data out and generate PST's.

Comment: Maybe I'm going about this all wrong.  Maybe I should use a tool that backs-up stuff via IMAP?  Is there a good batch-IMAP backup tool out there where I give it the credentials for 30 accounts and it goes through and downloads all the data?

Answer (score 2):

The Exchange Migration Wizard will do what you want; it became the Online Services Migration Tool a version or two ago.

The simplest alternative is probably to set up a (physical or virtual) machine with 30 IMAP profiles in Outlook, each pointed to a different PST. Secure it appropriately and voila. Instant backup mechanism.

Comment: So does it then just send/receive all the emails at once, or do you have to go in and switch between profiles? I'm just fuzzy on how the details of this would be if I actually got it set up.